# Fill JTable from database

Tags: java, sql, database, jtable, type-2-dimension

I write this simple code to fill `jTable1`, but it just fills `jTable1` with the last row from the database.

```
String SQL = "select * from usernames";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
String[] columnNames = {"Full Name", "Email"}; 
String n = "",e = "";
while(rs.next()) { 
    n = rs.getString("Full_Name");
    e = rs.getString("Email");
    Object[][]data = {{n,e}}; 
    jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by this code

```
String n = "",e = "";      

DefaultTableModel model;
model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
jTable1 = new  JTable(model);

model.addColumn("Full Name");
model.addColumn("Email");

while(rs.next())  
{
    n = rs.getString("Full_Name");    
    e= rs.getString("Email");   
    model.addRow(new Object[]{n,e});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will always be the last row since in the while loop you are creating a new JTable instead of appending a row to the existing one. So do like this,

```
// Code
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
while(rs.next())
{ 
    n = rs.getString("Full_Name");
    e= rs.getString("Email");
    //Object[][]data={{n,e}};
    // This will add row from the DB as the last row in the JTable. 
    model.insertRow(jtable1.getRowCount(), new Object[] {n, e});
}
```

Comment: can I just make change on this line                                < jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);> to add items to jTable1 without creating a new JTable each time.

Comment: I just tried for u. But I was unable to add it dynamically may be you could create an empty row and then use setValueAt(..) method to add. But still I am not sure abt this. Use model you can handle diff functions easily like adding, deleting, updating.